# insert get response into array of objects

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I´m using jquery get function to retrieve data from the server (Laravel application). The data is bysically an array of objects. Simplified the .js code  looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    var results = [];
    var getIt = function(){
        $.get('results', function(response){
            $.each(response, function(index, value){
                results.push(value);
            });
        });
    };
    getIt();
    console.log(results.length);
});
```

But the console logs 0, so the array is empty;
What is wrong with it. The array should be available
to later functions. Thanks for advice.

Comment: `$.get()` is asynchronous; you're trying to eat a pizza before it's been delivered. See the question I marked as duplicate for more details.

Comment: thank you all for your answers; i tried to search for it, but in a wrong direction; it sounds more clear now; thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `results` array before it has been populated.  You need to wait for your `GET /results` to return first.  Assuming the rest of your code works, the following change will `console.log` the populated array:

```
$(function(){
    var results = [];
    var getIt = function(){
        $.get('results', function(response){
            $.each(response, function(index, value){
                results.push(value);
            });

            console.log(results.length);
        });
    };
    getIt();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $.get is asynchronous, the `results` variable is still empty when the code is called. To see what I mean, try this:

```
$(function(){
    var results = [];
    var getIt = function(){
        $.get('results', function(response){
            $.each(response, function(index, value){
                results.push(value);
            });

           getIt();
           console.log(results.length);
        });
    };


});`
```